# Can't figure what lambda expression does stand for

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oop

I'm learning OOP in Unity and i found game with code build with oop, the problem is that i can't figure out what does line "private bool IsInitialized => _bulletPool != null;" stand for.

I've read about lambda expression and as i understood its used like an UnityAction or for writing shorter functions.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

[RequireComponent(typeof(CapsuleCollider2D))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(ShipAudio))]
public abstract class Ship : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] private Vector2 _shootDirection;

private BulletPool _bulletPool;

protected CapsuleCollider2D Collider;

private bool IsInitialized => _bulletPool != null; //this line

public event UnityAction Shooted;
public event UnityAction TookDamage;
public event UnityAction Died;

private void Awake()
{
    if (_shootDirection == Vector2.zero)
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(_shootDirection));

    Collider = GetComponent<CapsuleCollider2D>();
    Collider.isTrigger = true;
}

public void Init(BulletPool bulletPool)
{
    _bulletPool = bulletPool;
}

public void TakeDamage()
{
    OnTakeDamage();
    TookDamage?.Invoke();
}

public void Die()
{
    OnDie();
    Died?.Invoke();
}

public void Shoot()
{
    if (IsInitialized == false)
        throw new Exception("Impossible to shoot. Bullet pool is not stated");

    if (_bulletPool.TryGetObject(out Bullet bullet) == false)
        throw new Exception("Impossible to spawn bullet");

    bullet.Show();
    bullet.transform.position = transform.position;
    bullet.Init(_shootDirection);

    Shooted?.Invoke();
}

protected abstract void OnTakeDamage();

protected abstract void OnDie();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a shortcut syntax for a function or property getter.

```
private bool IsInitialized => _bulletPool != null;
```

Does exactly the same thing as this.

```
private bool IsInitialized
{
    get
    {
        return _bulletPool != null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not lambda expression it is expression bodied property. Basically it is equivalent for:

```
private bool IsInitialized
{
    get
    {
        return _bulletPool != null;
    }
}
```

You can see the decompilation [@sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboMLoN7LpHoAOATgJYBuAhgC4Cm6A9gEYBWDAxnegPqsArgBthDOgAVmzYQG5CxctXpNW04egCSAZ00A7CnQo1hFAF4Ng6ALwA+fkNHipM9AEJr6PSLnpkAXyA===) yourself.

See more - [Expression-bodied members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members).

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, a lambda expression is a shorter version of conditional statements. In the code, the condition is `bulletpool!=null`.

Since the result is true/false, the resulted value is assigned to the IsInitialized bool.

Hope you understand

Comment: This is incorrect. `bulletpool != null` is an expression, and the value of that expression is not _assigned_ to `IsInitialized`. The expression itself is assigned as the body of the getter for `IsInitialized`. Meaning that any time you get the value of `IsInitialized` you evaluate the expression at that moment.

Comment: Thank you so much, now I got a bigger picture on this expression